# List of all Windows 7 Event IDs and Sources?

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer, events

I'm looking for a complete list of *Sources + Event IDs* for Windows 7.

I known there's many web site with built-in search to find informations about a specific source + event id such as [Eventid.net](http://eventid.net) but what I'm looking for a *complete list* of these informations **or**, better, a *software* providing such information.

Many years ago I was using a program providing this information but, unfortunately I don't remember which one: may be from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit... (?) *EDIT*: I remember I was using this utilty in Windows XP Professional and the name was event"somethings" (for sure *not* `eventvwr.msc` or `eventcreate.exe`...)

My purpose is to create warnings with The Task scheduler when an important errors happen in the event log, such as Hard Disk errors and so on.

Comment: OK: i find it! The program is MPWizard.exe form the MOM 2005 Resource Tool kit:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/kevinholman/archive/2009/02/16/how-to-find-all-possible-event-id-s-for-a-given-event-source.aspx

Answer (score 10):

I don't believe that such a list exists today, since there are simply too many sources, each one managing its own errors.

Some places to find some of that information that I know of are :

[Microsoft Events and Errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299434%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
[Windows Security Log Events](http://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/default.aspx)

The website [eventid.net](http://www.eventid.net/search.asp) bills itself as having the best database for events ids.
You might be able to find more information from their search pages,
but that required paying for a subscription
(beware of auto-renewing subscriptions).

Comment: Plus, you can add your own event ids.

Comment: *> Plus, you can add your own event ids.*   Yup; drivers, programs, etc. will used their own, so technically it is *impossible* to have a “complete” list. The best you can do is to get a list of known and/or standard one ones. It’s just like with error messages and codes. Yes, for example error #2 is *usually* “file not found”. There are programs that list standard error message text for *known* error codes, but what about program ReallyCoolButNonStandardApp that returns error 2 for “no arguments specified”? RCBNSA’s error codes are probably not going to be in any regular list.

Comment: First thank you gentlemen for your answers. Both site MS and Eventid.net are well known search site for events but not a list. I finally found the program I was talking about. MPWizard.exe from the MOM 2005 Resource Tool kit... is it working on W7? I try it next week and give you some feed back. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a really great reference in a topic called [Events And Errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299434(v=ws.10).aspx)

I was looking for the possible eventid codes for [IIS 7 Application Pool recycling](http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/archive/2008/12/12/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log.aspx)

Those eventID codes are on this page: [IIS Application Pool Recycling](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349270(v=ws.10).aspx)